# git pull to my branch but do not overwrite any local files (that i already pushed to origin/branch as well)

Tags: git

My steps:

- I am on branch A (local)
- I made some changes to a file and committed and pushed the changes to branch A in origin.
- Other people made changes in master to other files and pushed to origin/master
- I want to pull their changes to my local branch A while not affecting my changes/new file.

How do i go about doing this?
I read that we could first do

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

However, my changes are already commited and pushed to origin branch A so when i do git stash i get the message `No local changes to save`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your local branch is `foo`. So you want to pull `master` to `foo`.

`git pull` without any options may not run as expected. It may be equivalent to `git pull origin foo` or doing nothing at all if configuration is not set yet. In this case, you need to explicitly specify which branch to pull from which remote.

```
git stash -u
# the remote is "origin" and the branch is "master"
git pull origin master
git stash apply --index
```

`-u` stashes the untracked files, which may already have been tracked by `master`. I prefer `apply` over `pop` as it does not remove the stash entry at once. `--index` resumes the staged files to the index instead of only to the working tree.